# Как сохранить конфиг ESLint?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, config, eslint

Есть ли возможность сохранить конфиг ESLint и в новых проектах создавать\подгружать уже с заданными настройками?

Надоело постоянно копировать настройки из предыдущих конфигов в ручную, есть ли какой-то вариант оптимизации этих действий? Может есть решение связанное не только с конфигом ESLint, но и прочими конфигами различных ПО?

Подскажите решения, локально для ESLint или универсальное для сохранения и развертывания различных конфигов, если такое есть

Comment: Делать стартер-паки с уже готовой сборкой для начала работы?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar Что-то в этом роде, да